# Adding an option to use twitter's profile picture as my current profile picture using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter

I am working on a reactJS based app. I have a screen where I can edit my profile details. There is a field named upload profile picture. I want to provide two options:
a ) upload via twitter
b ) custom upload (upload from phone gallery)

I have also added an optional field named "twitter profile link". My goal is to fetch the user's details from the twitter link provided [example: https://twitter.com/username ] - I should be able to fetch the profile picture and use it as my current profile picture.

Comment: Update: I also want to fetch the bio [profile description] along with the profile picture.

Comment: This is a little too broad for stackoverflow, especially because you don't provide any code. You'll most likely need to use the Twitter API to request that information. [Read about it here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show).

Comment: Hi Fabian, I have already with twitter API, but that is not working out to be exactly working as per my requirement. Coming to the coding, i have only worked on the UI part. I am searching for the logic but with absolutely no success rate. Anyways,Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the twitter api https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show endpoint. You're looking for the `"description"` and`"profile_image_url"` properties.